# Use OS and color theme specific icons for a toggle button in JPM

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, togglebutton

In Firefox, depending of the theme and OS, the icons are differents. Example:

On Linux:
[image: Linux]
On Windows 10:
[image: Windows]
<sub>(source: [saranitus.com](http://www.saranitus.com/wp-content/images/firefox/firefox-40-with-windows-10.png))</sub>

Lightweight theme:
[image: Personas]

Notice how the icons are darker on Windows 10 and white on a personas (Pretty obvious).

The thing is, [my addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/google-keep-panel/) adds a new button (a togglebutton, to be exact) to the Firefox menu, and for now only haves a static icon.
I know there was an addon made on JPM (or CFX, pretty much the same thing) that achieved this behavior, but I don't remember which one, nor do I remember how.
How can I make my icon change depending of the OS and theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was Mozilla's Addon Compatiblity Reporter.

Add this to your startup code:

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");

if ( Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0") > -1 ) {
    var icontype = "Modern";
}
else if ( Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Windows NT 6.3") > -1 || Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") > -1) {
    var icontype = "Metro";
}
else if ( Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") > -1 || Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") > -1) {
    var icontype = "Aero";
}
else if ( Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").navigator.oscpu.indexOf("Mac OS X") > -1 ) {
    var icontype = "Aqua";
}
else {
    var icontype = "Linux";
```

}

And then, when declaring your icons, simply type that:

```
icon: {
  "16": "./" + icontype + "_16.png",
  "32": "./" + icontype + "_32.png"
},
```

So when you created an icon for Mac OS X, drop it as `data/Aqua_16.png` and it should work.